# How to fix column alignment for Ag-Grid?

Tags: npm, vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working on responsive web application and using ag-grid to fill data. The problem is in my master data number of columns are dynamic so my grid size is wide but when the columns are less in number the header and rows does not seem to be aligned. I tried various properties like

```
rowDragManaged : true, 
animateRows : true
```

but its not working. But its not getting fixed I went through the documentation but found no option is it a bug in their product?

[image]

Comment: pinned: 'left 'works but hiding the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Looks like you're doing something weird, it's not normally like that. I would have to see a demo reproducing the problem to have any hope of figuring it out.